# HTTP request with Python : TypeError: an integer is required (got type socket)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http, request

I'm facing a really strange bug while trying to retrieve a resource via HTTP. It seems to happen with any HTTP client (tried requests and urllib with the same results).

My project uses django, and I run my tests using tox and the standard django command `python manage.py test`. When I run my test suite and a unit test makes a HTTP request (e.g via `requests.get('http://example.com')`), the tests fails with an error, the test suite continue until the end, and hangs. I have to manually kill the process via command line.

After some investigations, I put a `try / except` block arount the http request, and got the following stacktrace:

```
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 68, in get
  return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
  response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
  timeout=timeout
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
  body=body, headers=headers)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
  conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1065, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 906, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 841, in send
  self.connect()
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 155, in connect
  conn = self._new_conn()
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
  (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "/mycomputer/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 68, in create_connection
  sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 123, in __init__
  _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type socket)
```

I really don't understand the problem here. Running the same thing from the command line works perfectly, so it's probably related to my project architecture. Also, running the test suite on another computer fails the same way.

Have anybody meet a similar issue ? What can I do do track down the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, the problem was caused by [HTTPretty](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/issues/221), a third-party package I use for mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I've read that django is not a full server and can cause problems when you try to use it as one. Perhaps this is one of this cases.

Did you try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/ ?

Comment: Sorry if I was'nt  clear : i'm not doing requests against my own site. All the requests are done against third party APIs. So I' don't think it's related to django's built-in webserver.